# What is the pattern '<front>' referred to in Drupal speak?

Tags: 8

Is the pattern  used to denote the front page in Drupal referred to as token or something else? Does it exist in Drupal 8?

Comment: It probably doesn't have an official name. It's referred to in more than one place in core simply as a _path_. Some examples: 1. _Tests the fromRoute() method with the special <front> path._, 2. _The four permutations of the special '<front>' path_, 3. _Whether the current page is the front page (which implies the current path might also be <front>)_

Comment: Strictly speaking I guess you might say it's a _route_, given that it's defined in system.routing.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this Drupal 8 issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2421941), `<front>` is a "special token." Yes, it still works in Drupal 8.

Reading the whole issue queue will give you some insight into the core developers' thought processes as they decided whether or not to support this legacy Drupalism in Drupal 8. They had a lot of good reasons to drop support for it, but they erred on the side of caution and left it in.

You can also try it for yourself in a Drupal 8 site; it definitely still works!

Help text for adding a menu link says:

> Start typing the title of a piece of content to select it. You can also enter an internal path such as `/node/add` or an external URL such as `http://example.com`. Enter `<front>` to link to the front page.

I guess you might want to give more weight to Clive's comments above, since his answer is based on the actual code and comments in Drupal core. Technically, all strings processed by `index.php` are considered "paths" and the ones that resolve to valid destinations are "routes." (Under the hood, [Drupal 8's routing system](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/routing-system-overview) is based on the routing provided by the Symfony HTTP kernel, and is used to connect paths to controller logic.)

Comment: Or more simply, `<front>` is a unique identifier in Drupal that will always refer to the designated item set as the homepage of the site.

Comment: <front> is a route name as @Clive's commented, but the route is only a dummy route and Drupal makes sure it is never resolved by replacing `/` with the configured front page before routes are matched.